# Blob upload with axios fail in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have been trying to upload files using axios, the payload on the console network tab looks great but the files appear to be empty on the Laravel side.

Below is the response I get from `$request->all()`

```
"feedback": {
"description": "there is not a friend",
"displays": [
 "Lagos -\r\n Ikoyi"
],
"messages": [
 {
   "text": "this is an unexpected result",
   "startTime": "2018-02-20T11:11:01.404Z",
   "endTime": "2018-02-20T11:11:01.411Z",
   "image": {},
   "video": {}
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Below is the send method:

```
submit() {

           const data = new FormData();
           data.append('description', this.description);
           for (let index in this.boards) {
               if (this.boards.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                   data.append('displays[' + index + ']', this.boards[index]);
               }
           }
           for (let index in this.messages) {
               if (this.messages.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                   data.append('messages[' + index + '][text]', this.messages[index].text);
                   data.append('messages[' + index + '][image]', this.messages[index].imageBlob);
                   data.append('messages[' + index + '][video]', this.messages[index].videoBlob);
                   data.append('messages[' + index + '][startTime]', this.messages[index].startTime);
                   data.append('messages[' + index + '][endTime]', this.messages[index].endTime);
               }
           }

           axios.post('/campaign/', data, {
               headers: {
                   'accept': 'application/json',
                   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                   'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
               }
           }).then(response => {
               this.feedback = response.data;
           }).catch(error=>{
               this.errors = error
           });
       }
```

Please, how can I work around that?

Comment: I don't think BLOB is sent as a `$_FILES` to the server, the way you're sending.  It'll probably be just a parameter in the `$_POST` method.

Comment: Thanks @Phiter 
Using `$_POST` does not show the files except `$_FILES` which shows these below:

Comment: `{
  "feedback": {
    "messages": {
      "name": [
        {
          "image": "blob",
          "video": "blob"
        }
      ],
      "type": [
        {
          "image": "image/jpeg",
          "video": "video/mp4"
        }
      ],
      "tmp_name": [
        {
          "image": "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php628F.tmp",
          "video": "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php62A0.tmp"
        }
      ],
      "error": [
        {
          "image": 0,
          "video": 0
        }
      ],
      "size": [
        {
          "image": 49379,
          "video": 17837596

Comment: If I can get the name of the actual file I would be fine than showing `blob` as the value.

Comment: how do you set `image`?

Comment: Hello @Phiter
This is the pen of how I set the image https://codepen.io/Cejowisz/pen/RQQdPL

Comment: Hello@Phiter and everyone. Please help me on this. Thanks